# How to get rendered tree data on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

How can I get all rendered tree `metadata` on page load in `jstree`, something like this output:

```
[23,24]
```

Note: i want put each `id` in `metadata` object to be like this on page load `[23,24]`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#jstree').jstree({
    "json_data": {
      "data": [{
        "data": "A node",
        "metadata": { id: 23 },
        "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"]
      }, {
        "metadata": { "id": 24 },
        "data": "Node 2",
      }]
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `id` values you can use `map()` on the array you provide to the jsTree instance, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var treeStructure = [{
    "data": "A node",
    "metadata": { id: 23 },
    "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"]
  }, {
    "metadata": { "id": 24 },
    "data": "Node 2",
  }];
  
  var ids = treeStructure.map(function(o) {
    return o.metadata.id;
  });
  console.log(ids);

  $('#jstree').jstree({
    "json_data": {
      "data": treeStructure
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree"></div>
```